# Convert JSON-LD to d3.js node/links format?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, d3.js

I'm trying to make a visualization of an OWL ontology. I have converted it to JSON-LD but now need to get it to D3's node/links format? For reference the format looks like this:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"x": 469, "y": 410},
    {"x": 493, "y": 364},
    {"x": 442, "y": 365},
    {"x": 467, "y": 314},
    {"x": 477, "y": 248},
    {"x": 425, "y": 207},
    {"x": 402, "y": 155},
    {"x": 369, "y": 196},
    {"x": 350, "y": 148},
    {"x": 539, "y": 222},
    {"x": 594, "y": 235},
    {"x": 582, "y": 185},
    {"x": 633, "y": 200}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1},
    {"source":  1, "target":  2},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  1, "target":  3},
    {"source":  3, "target":  2},
    {"source":  3, "target":  4},
    {"source":  4, "target":  5},
    {"source":  5, "target":  6},
    {"source":  5, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  8},
    {"source":  7, "target":  8},
    {"source":  9, "target":  4},
    {"source":  9, "target": 11},
    {"source":  9, "target": 10},
    {"source": 10, "target": 11},
    {"source": 11, "target": 12},
    {"source": 12, "target": 10}
  ]
}
```

I know I can open up a json file using d3.json, but I'm unsure on how exactly I can go from JSON-LD to the format above. Any solutions? Thanks.

EDIT:

My owl ontology is available on pastebin here (in json-ld format): http://pastebin.com/g7ggDyFX. If you take a peak at the context you can see that I'm modelling the ontology by the "isSubClass" property.

I know that to read json files in D3 I can use d3.json. I'm unsure how exactly to convert to the format above though.

I found this github repository https://github.com/uf6/ottograf that says it should be able to convert to the format, but I'm having a lot of trouble running it, and I also want to keep it in javascript. Any tips/solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data in JSON-LD format?

Comment: can this subset of your JSON-LD data: `{
      "@id": "schema:Person",
      "@type": "owl:Class",
      "subClassOf": {
        "@id": "gr:BusinessEntity"
      }
    }` be translated as one edge between two nodes `schema:Person` and `gr:BusinessEntity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you want to do is convert this:

```
{
  "@id": "schema:Person"
  , "@type": "owl:Class"
  , "subClassOf": { 
    "@id": "gr:BusinessEntity"
  }
}
```

into

```
{
  "nodes": [
    { "@id": "schema:Person", "@type": "owl:Class"}
    { "@id": "gr:BusinessEntity"}
  ]
  , "links": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1}
  ]
}
```

What you need to do is the following:

Once the json data is loaded, process it via a conversion function you will write:

1. Loop through the @graph array

Inside this loop, keep a record of each node, and also a record of each link. For the nodes, make sure to use an object so that you get unique nodes.

2. Loop through the nodes object, and create your "nodes" array based on it
3. create your "links" array by looking up the index of each node in the nodes array...

You may want to have a look at the archives of d3.js mailing list, some people have already asked similar questions as yours.